# How to call a setter function from one class in another class?

Tags: c++, function, class, setter

I'm trying to call the setter function from `Class A` in `class B` but I'm unable to do this and I don't know why. *(I'm a beginner in C++ and I need to do this as it's related to my assignment.)*

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
private:
  int i = 2;
public:
  int getInt(){
    return i;
  };
  void setI(int a){
    i = a;
  }
};

class B{
private:
  int c = 3;
public:
  void setAI(A a){
    a.setI(c);
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;

  cout << a.getInt() << endl;
  b.setAI(a);
  cout << a.getInt() << endl;
  a.setI(5);
  cout << a.getInt() << endl;
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
2
2
5
```

When I want to get:

```
2
3
5
```

Comment: In `void setAI(A a)` you're copying A. You need to take it by reference (`void setAI(A& a)`) otherwise you're modifying a copied value.

Comment: Oh, I see I was just learning about pointers recently and didn't realize. Tyvm for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I just made some changes in the `setAI()` function. I have passed the object by address rather than value. I'm not sure of what was causing the problem (as I'm also a beginner) but the pointer has solved the problem.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
private:
  int i = 2;
public:
  int getInt(){
    return i;
  };
  void setI(int a){
    i = a;
  }
};

class B{
private:
  int c = 3;
public:
  void setAI(A *a){
      a->setI(c);
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;

  cout << a.getInt() << endl;
  b.setAI(&a);
  cout << a.getInt() << endl;
  a.setI(5);
  cout << a.getInt() << endl;
}
```

Comment: The problem is a very common beginner misunderstanding. In this code `setAI(A a)` `a` is a **copy**, your setter is working but it is changing a **copy** instead of the object you really want to change. By changing your code to use a pointer you avoided any object being copied. You could also have used a reference, like this `setAI(A& a)`. I'm not sure why so many beginners get this wrong, I guess people don't expect passing parameters to create copies of objects, but it does.